# String concatenation with escaped variables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string

Rather simple question

I've got a SQL string similar to the following:

```
query = "select * from table_name where name ='"+varName+"' and 
date ='"+varDate+"' order by state desc";
```

The *varName*, *varDate* are defined from a previous select query on another db's table. Their values may have ' : / and other special characters within.

Is there a way either by use of C# or SQL that I can "escape" the contents of the varName, varDate in the above select statement?

I'd prefer not to covert special characters :)

EDIT:

Forgot to include - the setup is MSSQL

Comment: please look into SQL injection

Comment: What are you using to query the database? You should really be using `Parameterized` queries.

Comment: Why do you query the database and use the results as "parameters" for another query? Would it not be better to do it all in one query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parameterise your queries using any reasonably mature API. This support is offered in ADO.NET:

```
string query = "select * from table_name where name = @name and date = @date order by state desc";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
{
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", name);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", date);
  using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
  { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I believe this should do it. Using this method, are there any other recommendations for injection prevention? The console application we are making is for demonstration (not production) but I still would appreciate any further guidance.

Comment: @RayAlex As a general rule of thumb, never trust any input you don't control. However in this instance no further checking of input data is required - this should be sufficient to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Yep. In this case though I shouldn't have to worry too much given that this program will not accept any user input at any time (to be run as a scheduled task). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would keep it compiled in a storead procedure

note:
regardless the escape, ur current code is wide open for sql injection

Comment: Indeed. I'm looking for a method that both allows for literal writing of special characters and provides a reasonable amount of protection against injection